# Why is my PC doing more than one DNS query for www.ietf.org?

Tags: domain-name-system, wireshark, cloudflare

I'm doing an exercise for a class where I have to flush the DNS cache and then visit [www.ietf.org](http://www.ietf.org) and capture the packets. I got this:

[image]

The selected query and response are the "main" ones. What about the others? Looks like a redirect. My guess is that the 2nd and 3rd queries also have to do with finding both the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple queries because of using CNAME records, which is very often the case when using CDNs.

You can see it easily:

```
$ dig www.ietf.org +noall +ans
www.ietf.org.       16m2s IN CNAME www.ietf.org.cdn.cloudflare.net.
www.ietf.org.cdn.cloudflare.net. 5m IN A 104.16.45.99
www.ietf.org.cdn.cloudflare.net. 5m IN A 104.16.44.99
```

But that is because the recursive nameserver did iterate to give you the reply.
If you do it step by step you can find what happens:

```
$ dig www.ietf.org +norecurse A
[..]
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.ietf.org.       13m23s IN CNAME www.ietf.org.cdn.cloudflare.net.
```

and then:

```
$ dig www.ietf.org.cdn.cloudflare.net. A
[..]
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.ietf.org.cdn.cloudflare.net. 5m IN A 104.16.44.99
www.ietf.org.cdn.cloudflare.net. 5m IN A 104.16.45.99

$ dig www.ietf.org.cdn.cloudflare.net. AAAA
[..]
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.ietf.org.cdn.cloudflare.net. 5m IN AAAA 2606:4700::6810:2d63
www.ietf.org.cdn.cloudflare.net. 5m IN AAAA 2606:4700::6810:2c63
```

A smart applications nowadays is expected to use both AAAA and A record types to resolve names, and giving a slight preference to IPv6. This is for example explained in the "Happy Eyeballs" algorithm.

PS: there is no "redirect" in the DNS so please don't use that term in this context; redirections are an HTTP level matter, far over/after what happens at the DNS layer.